# Why do I see '\n' seen when reading from a text file? (python)

Tags: python, text-files

```
text_file = open("Accounts.txt")
Accounts = text_file.read().split(',').strip
```

I'm reading a text file using this and splitting it into a list however, when I print this list the output has the desired values with '\n' in it. However, when opening the text file I dont see this string

```
f = open("Accounts.txt",'a')
f.write(Combined)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

This was how I was writing to the text file.

Comment: `\n` is a newline character. The line breaks in your file are represented as `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Text files have a newline character in them which is different depending on whether you are on windows or linux.

Since you didn't say which system you're on, I'm assuming that's what's going on here. You should also read text files in binary mode generally. I would also recommend using the with statement to close is called automatically.

```
with open("Accounts.txt",'ab') as f:
    f.write(Combined)
    f.write('\n')
```

Comment: ['AH\nAH\nAH\n'] is the output and I'm on windows with "AH" being the desired values. I am a novice in python but I wanted to read from the text file as a list so that I can see if an input is in this list.